# Error TS2307 after migrating a project from Angular 11 to Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I migrated my project from Angular 11 to Angular 12. I got errors using the ng update. So I took the raw way of doing it.

I created a fresh new Angular 12 project, added the dependencies all over again, and then replaced the src folder. The Angular 11 project had the default values in the config files. So I thought I can just use the defaults of Angular 12.

But again, I find the build logs flooded with error TS2307 for local filed.

I can see the file is present in the folder. But I still get this error

```
Error: src/app/components/open-orders/open-orders.component.ts:2:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/data/Order' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the open-orders.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Order } from 'src/app/data/Order';
import { CloudService } from 'src/app/services/cloud.service';
```

I get the same error for the two local imports

Getting the same error when I use relative paths

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Order } from '../../data/Order';
import { CloudService } from '../../services/cloud.service';
```

I searched the net and tried the various tweaks (in tsconfig.json and angular.json) to get over the TS2307, but none of them seem to work.

Is this related to Angular 12? Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: why did you update project manually instead of using angular ng- update..?

Comment: It's looking for a module at the path `src/app/data/Order`. So, do you have such module? Is the path correct?

Comment: @Edison I got the same problem when I updated with ng update. So I tried the brute force way.

Comment: Can you show open-orders.component.ts ?

Comment: @MikeOne I think this is where the error is - he's upgrading from angular 2 to 12 so outside of ivy rendering rxjs, the router and several other libraries have subtle differences.

Comment: @MikeOne I have added the imports part of the open-orders.component.ts above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because it's searching for a module at `src/app/data/Order` which is missing. go check your path and look if such a module exists.

Comment: he may also want to look at the relative path - instead of src/app - try ./../../

Comment: As I mentioned, it is working code, and all the code is present in there. I believe this is some problem with some configuration settings, that is not taking the the root folder correctly.

Comment: @chrisburd I tried the ../.. structure. but I still get the same error.

Comment: do you see the data/order folder?

try and place the relative path that way to it till it no longer errors.  Or there is a problem with the module itself.  so check the Order module - its either not there as the other person commented or it as something that needs to change in one of the components.  which is probably the later.   find out which component and if you're stuck post that component so we can all help you.

Comment: @chrisburd Yes, I tried the relative path. But still getting the same error. I am getting this error for all the local imports.

Comment: The original code was developed on Windows. Because of that, some file names had incorrect case. This  caused problem when compiling on Linux.